# what is the valid monthly active user number?

Tags: metrics, google-fabric, active-users

I would like to ask about a metric. I can see the monthly active user number in case of export to excel file.

For sure, the datas are seperated to Daily, Weekly, Monthly columns.

What are the exact, valid active user number for a month?

For example from 03.01 - 03.31 period, the last number at the end of the month, so the monthly active user's number at the day of 03.31? Or for example the average of the all monthly active user's number of march? Or the sum of the daily active user's number of march?

Answer (score 0):

For the deprecated Fabric Answers: the window for data being captured is a 30-day rolling window - so if you're looking at 3/31, the MAU stat is capturing active user data from 3/2-3/31. Similarly, if you're looking at a date halfway through a month, it will be showing data from that day to halfway through the month before. The metric it's counting specifically is the amount of users in the last 30 day rolling window that have recorded activity within your app.

If you're also looking at Firebase Analytics, it's also a rolling window, but I believe it by default shows you a 28 day view rather than 30 days.